# Error with .webp images when using Active Storage on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webp, rails-activestorage

When I use Active Storage, and when someone upload a .webp image, and when I run `file.attach(io: webp_file, filename: 'file.webp')` it works, and then ActiveStorage automatically run a job `ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob`

But this job raises :

```
MiniMagick::Error (`identify -format %[orientation] /tmp/ActiveStorage-114989-20180905-4-wak8ob.webp[0]` failed with error:
identify-im6.q16: delegate failed `'dwebp' -pam '%i' -o '%o'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1919.
identify-im6.q16: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-1400SWBHj-p67HrV': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
```

Although I am on Heroku-18, and so there is a lib called "libwepb6" (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages)

Do I have to create a Heroku buildpack?

Answer (score 13):

Had the same problem. Here's the step by step:

1 - Add this to development.rb and production.rb to force rails to accept WEBP.

```
config.active_storage.variable_content_types = %w(
  image/png
  image/gif
  image/jpg
  image/jpeg
  image/webp
  image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
  image/vnd.microsoft.icon
)
```

2 - Add [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to your app on heroku, making sure it's the first pack. It allows you to install ubuntu packages that are not already preinstalled.

3 - Navigate to the root of your app (where your Gemfile is) and run the commands below to create a file named `AptFile`, and add the `webp`package to it.

```
touch Aptfile
echo "webp" >> Aptfile
```

4 - Redeploy your app.

Heroku will now install the missing `webp` package that imagemagick needs to handle webp images.

**Edit: Step 1 is not necessary if you are on Rails 6.1 or later.**

Comment: This worked perfectly for my app. `rails_admin` did not work nicely however and after some digging I realized I had to add `webp` to this line https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/98ddea1260d018c0a2f0072445b6569328627586/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/multiple_active_storage.rb#L21. I'm leaving this here in case it helps others in the future.

Comment: on ubuntu, the configuration you listed and installing the webp works for me
`sudo apt-get install webp`

Answer (score -1):

Edit: So S3 is being used and `/tmp` for manipulation.

Looking at the error it seems to delegate to `dwebp` fine, so I have to assume it was built correctly. If it wasn't built with webp you would get a delegate error like so

```
identify.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `1.sm.webp' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
```

You can make sure by running `heroku run "identify -list format | grep -i WebP"`

The error seems to be on the `/tmp/` file directory access.
How's the space situation? `df -h`

Note that on a Mac I get this, notice the use of the `/var` directory:

```
~/w/p ❯❯❯ identify 1.sm.webp
Decoded /var/folders/lk/z_bvyjj939d94mvkx6rz9700fbx9gg/T/magick-99980zzj1IT0Lkx7L. Dimensions: 320 x 214 . Format: lossy. Now saving...
Saved file /var/folders/lk/z_bvyjj939d94mvkx6rz9700fbx9gg/T/magick-999803WU_TvRo7xdJ
1.sm.webp PAM 320x214 320x214+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 273989B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Probably this heroku employee will shed more light on this.

This article also goes into detail https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku, especially this point:

> While file uploads that are stored with the :local option will appear
>   to work at first, the attachments will exhibit seemingly strange
>   behavior and eventually disappear.

with recommendations to use cloud storage (e.g. Amazon S3).

Comment: thank you, I use Amazon S3 and Active Storage uses tmp files for processing files, it works for .jpg, .png but not .webp, I think a library is really missing

Comment: Looks like the issue has to do with the libraries that imagemagick supports on Heroku. I'm investigating now on the platform (I work there).
`$heroku run bash; ~ $ curl https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.webp -O
~ $ identify 1.sm.webp
identify-im6.q16: delegate failed 'dwebp' -pam '%i' -o '%o'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1919.`